# How to find VLC running on local network from android device

Tags: java, android, vlc

I need my android app to find vlc running on the local network. I've found several apps that seem to do just this but I can't seem to find much about how to go about doing it. I think I am supposed to use Network Service Discovery. The only tutorial I've found is http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html and I haven't been able to get it working or understand how to configure it for vlc. If someone could outline the steps for me or point me to relevant tutorials I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like a way to hack the media players on a network. Are you sure this is a good idea?

Comment: I wanted to stream audio and video to vlc running on the local network. I've seen apps that do this. Is there something unsafe about doing this?

Comment: Normally VLC contacts your media server and asks it for what it wants.  The server doesn't find VLC clients to push media to.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to tell VLC what to ask for?

Comment: You can tell the user of the VLC what to use.